# »Eric erzählt [seinen/seinem] Brüdern Witze.«

Tags: dative, accusative, adjective-ending

I was wondering what would be the right way to say:

> Eric erzählt seinen Brüdern Witze.

I thought we should use *seinem* here since *Brüdern* is a indirect object but “German notes” I have borrowed from a friend shows otherwise *seinen.*

Comment: _seinem Bruder_ but _seinen Brüdern_. It's plural.

Comment: First of all: In German grammar there is nothing like direct or indirect objects. We have objects in four different cases (nominative, genitive, dative and accusative) plus prepositional object, but neither direct nor indirect objects. But, we have also something, that also English has: grammatical number: singular and plural!

Comment: To be more precise: both dative and accusative objects are direct objects in German while indirect objects (here called *prepositional objects*) are an entirely different thing altogether. And the rare genitive objects are also direct objects.

Comment: Lots of answers in comments and then this perfectly understandable question is closed. Sometimes I don't understand why people here are so keen on closing questions.

Comment: @Olafant It was closed as *off-topic*, not as *unclear*

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf It's perfectly understandable (if you try) that *seinen* makes you wonder because you expect dative case. That question shows that OP was at an important point of his learning - a really good and reasonable question popped up in OP's mind. And then the question (that was answered by a mod) is getting closed as off-topic. Does that make any sense? Not to me.

Comment: @Olafant you are barking at the wrong tree. I never said it was unclear, and you can see who did vote to cloes - I was none of them. I just pointed out to a mistake in your argumentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Seinen* is correct, because there are multiple brothers. If there were only one, *seinem* would be correct